# OpenTok - Tokbox - System Audio

Tags: javascript, webrtc, opentok, tokbox

Is there any way to publish the system's audio output to a webRTC stream using TokBox (OpenTok)?

Looking to do something like Skype which lets us send through the *System Audio* in addition to the Microphone.

Thanks.

Comment: What platform are you using? Is this for the browser using opentok.js or are you using iOS or Android?

Comment: @AdamUllman Using opentok.js in the browser

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235077/capture-system-sound-from-browser